# Java - Recursion and Nesting of Tasks, incorrect parent

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, parent-child, nested

Some Context:


I am working with a system which uses a profile to pass all of the data around;

- Each Profile has an ArrayList<Event> events
- Each Event contains an ArrayList<Task> tasks
- Each Task contains an ArrayList<Task> subtasks

When adding a Subtask, the system ends up putting the new Subtask as a child of the main Event, rather than the desired parent. I have narrowed the issue down to this block of code.

---

The big question:
Will this series of methods bring about the immediate parent task of an eligible (child/subtask)?

(Keep in mind, each child is in an ArrayList within the parent.)

```
     //--getParent(Task, Event) finds the nearest parent task of child, if none: null    
        public Task getParent(Task child, Event event){
            Task parent = null;
        for(Task t : event.getTasks()){
            if (t.getId() == child.getId())
                return parent;
        }
        for (Task t : event.getTasks()){
            parent = checkParent(child, t);
            if (parent != null)
                break;
        }
        return parent;
        }

        //--checkParent(Task, Task) checks if child is contained in parent.Subtasks;
        private Task checkParent(Task child, Task parent){
            ArrayList subtasks = parent.getSubtasks();
            for (Task t : subtasks)
            {
                if (t.getId() == child.getId())
                {
                    return parent;
                }
            }
            for (Task t : subtasks)
            {
                parent = checkParent(child, t);
                if (parent != null)
                    break;
            }
            return parent;
        }
```

---

To provide a bit more context, I am developing in the Android environment. Here is the method which makes the calls to retrieve the parent:

```
public void saveTask(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EventTaskViewerActivity.class);
        while (currentEventId != currentParentId && currentParentId != -1){
            Task parent = dataManager.getTask(currentParentId, currentEventId);
            Task superTask = dataManager.getParent(parent, currentEvent);
            if (superTask != null)
                currentParentId = superTask.getId();
            else {
                currentParentId = currentEventId;
                Event e = dataManager.addTaskToEvent(buildTaskFromActivity(), currentEvent);
                dataManager.updateEvent(e);
                break;
            }

        }

        intent.putExtra("CURRENT_USER_ID", androidId);
        intent.putExtra("CURRENT_EVENT_ID", currentEventId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: So your code is not working?

Comment: How did you narrow down the issue?  I don't see any obvious bugs in this piece of code, although I haven't stepped through it with a debugger.  Do you actually have a test case that shows it failing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain what this bit of code is doing in relation to the rest of your code. Specifically, your question states that:

> When adding a Subtask, the system ends up putting the new Subtask as a
>   child of the main Event, rather than the desired parent.

However, the bit of code you've provided is the retrieval and checking rather than the addition of a sub-task. I think seeing the checkParent() method would help, as well as maybe seeing the methods that add sub-tasks.

Without that, the one thing I did notice that seems like it might be out of place:

```
Task parent = null;
    for(Task t : event.getTasks()){
        if (t.getId() == child.getId())
            return parent;
    }
```

You set `parent = null` and then run a loop checking every task within the event. If any task has the same ID as the child, then you return a null value. Are you wanting to return null in that case or are you wanting to return the `Event` as the parent?

Comment: No, this was intentional.  If the Task that we're looking for is one of the immediate children of the Event, then it doesn't have a Task for its parent, so we return null.  It's only when we start looking at subtasks that we would want to return non-null and that's what the confusingly named `checkParent` does.

Comment: David is spot on with my intentions, so I provided a bit of additional context to the issue, (i.e the saveTask(View) method)